# How to control child-thread lifecycle and synchonize it with main-thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to create another thread that processes data while main thread doing some more. Main thread must wait till another thread finishes `doStuff` with all elements.
And my implementation is pretty straight forward.

Please, take a look at `processData` and tell me is there some more Java-like way to do it?

I read about `Phaser` but still can't imagine how to use it or what else can I try?

```
public class MyClass {
    private final NodeQueue queue;
    
    MyClass() {
        queue = new NodeQueue();
    }
    
    public void processData(Set<String> dataSet) {
        // allow transfer
        queue.transferEnable()
        Thread transfer = new Thread(() -> {
            queue.transferData();
        })
        transfer.start();
        
        // doStuff in another thread
        for (String element : dataSet) {
            queue.add(element);
            // do something more
        }
        
        // stop transfer
        queue.waitTillEmptyQueue();
        queue.transferDisable();
        try {
            transfer.join();
        } catch (...) {
            // catch
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public class NodeQueue {
        private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> queue;
        
        private boolean transferEnabled;
        
        protected NodeQueue() {
            queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
            transferEnabled = true;
        }
        
        protected void transfer() {
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                doStuff(queue.poll());
            }
        }
        
        public void transferData() {
            while (tranfserEnabled) {
                transfer();
            }
        }
        
        public synchronized void transferEnable() {
            transferEnabled = true;
        }
        
        public synchronized void transferDisable() {
            transferEnabled = false;
        }
        
        public void add(String s) {
            queue.add(s);
        }
        
        public synchronized void waitTillEmptyQueue() {
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seem like a classic producer-consumer problem. I'd suggest to use some `BlockingQueue` as a mediator. The `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is more suitable as a pool for exchanging data between multiple threads .
Also the shared switch `transferEnabled` will not work correctly without `volatile` as the `NodeQueue` could still see `false` after the write from main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me copy the `Phaser` example from [my own post](https://dev.to/franzwong/wait-for-completion-of-all-tasks-with-java-phaser-1g8m)

Main thread

```java
// Add producer as a party
Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);

for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i) {
  // Add each task as a party
  phaser.register();
  queue.put(new Task());
}

// Producer arrived and wait for completion of all tasks
phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();

// At the end, there is only 1 party left which is the producer itself
```

Consumer

```java
while (true) {
  Task task = queue.take();
  processTask(task);
  // Task completed and remove itself as a party
  phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
}
```